# How to post list data to .net mvc using Axios with out [FromBody] model binding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, axios

I am try to post object list to backend using `Axios`.

But backend couldn't get any object list parameters.

Code:

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <button onclick="postData()">Post Data</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
<script>
    function postData() {
        let mockData = [];
        mockData.push({ ID: 0, Name: "John" });
        mockData.push({ ID: 1, Name: "Mary" });
        mockData.push({ ID: 2, Name: "Alex" });
        mockData.push({ ID: 3, Name: "July" });
        mockData.push({ ID: 4, Name: "Steve" });
        console.log(mockData);


        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('model', mockData);

        axios.post('/Home/Receive', formData)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch((error) => { console.error(error) });
    }
</script>
```

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Receive(List<MemberInfo> model)
        {
            var itemList = model;
            return View();
        }

        public class MemberInfo
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

The above code, backend always get null.

Result:
[image: My js object array]
[image: Couldn't get parameters]

> Awayls get null when post to this function.

Even I add `[FromQuery]` or `[FromForm]` in function.
[image: Add <code>[FromQuery]</code>]

I know I can use `[FromBody]` to get object list. So how can I get object list without `[FromBody]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code of your controller action and model class, to post data and bind value to properties of the model, you can try:

Approach 1: generate and post formdata like below on your JavaScript client side.

```
function postData() {
    let mockData = [];
    mockData.push({ ID: 0, Name: "John" });
    mockData.push({ ID: 1, Name: "Mary" });
    mockData.push({ ID: 2, Name: "Alex" });
    mockData.push({ ID: 3, Name: "July" });
    mockData.push({ ID: 4, Name: "Steve" });
    console.log(mockData);


    const formData = new FormData();
    //formData.append('model', JSON.stringify(mockData));
    for (var i = 0; i < mockData.length; i++) {
        formData.append(`model[${i}].ID`, mockData[i].ID);
        formData.append(`model[${i}].Name`, mockData[i].Name);
    }


    axios.post('/Home/Receive', formData)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch((error) => { console.error(error) });
}
```

Approach 2: implement and use your own custom model binder, like below.

*MemberInfoModelBinder class*

```
public class MemberInfoModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // ...
        // implement it based on your actual requirement
        // code logic here
        // ...

        //var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        //{
        //    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        //};

        var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MemberInfo>>(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("model").FirstOrDefault());

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

*Receive action*

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Receive(
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MemberInfoModelBinder))]List<MemberInfo> model)
{
    var itemList = model;
    return View();
}
```

*On JavaScript client side*

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('model', JSON.stringify(mockData));
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: First way is working! I finally can post object list to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking you post action like this:

```
axios.post('/Home/Receive', formData)
```

Will always put the data in the body of the request.

If you wish to get it for example from query, you would have to adjust both the backend and the client javascript call:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Receive([FromQuery]List<MemberInfo> model)
        {
            var itemList = model;
            return View();
        }


... JS

        axios.get('/Home/Receive', formData)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch((error) => { console.error(error) });
```

Update:

If you want it as a POST action, without the `[FromBody]` attribute, you can add a `[ApiController]` attribute to your controller - that's the second option you could use

Comment: I want `Post` object array to this function instead of use get method. And I wish it could auto bind model .